# Subtitle synthsizer for audio/video files

Tags: video, audio, machine-learning, speech-recognition, subtitles

I'm looking for a speech recognition utility which generates subtitles. That is, given an audio file (or audio-and-video file), attempts to decipher the segments of spoken text in the audio, and generates a best-effort subtitle file with the text at different segments.

In this age of neural-network-learning, I'm betting this is no longer such an out-of-reach problem. Plus, it seems Google seems to have something like this on YouTube, albeit proprietary.

Required features:

- gratis
- Works on Linux
- Supports at least one or two common audio (or A/V) formats
- Must try to differentiate sentences / speech by different people - not just dump a long bunch of many paragraphs of text.

Desired features

- libre
- actively maintained
- high accuracy rate
- Supports many formats
- Multi-platform

Comment: Apple's built-in Dictation utility can do the recognition part of this & transcribe to a text file, though it's a bit of a hack, as that's not what it was designed for. See https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2022/how-transcribe-audio-text-using-dictation-on-mac for a guide. It's been part of the OS about 10 years & can work offline as well as online.

Comment: Modern browsers may have speech recognition API. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition if you are interested in programming a bit.

Comment: @Marcel: 1. This is SR.SX, not SO...  2. The Web API specification is just that, a spec, not a product (nor a service). As far as I can tell, anyway.